# Nested polymer elements not showing up?

Tags: nested, polymer

A simple nested `polymer-element` inside another one will not display:

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="lib/polymer.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="import" href="elements/indx-grid.html">
        <link rel="import" href="elements/indx-griditem.html">
        <title>INDX-polymer</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <indx-grid>
            <indx-griditem></indx-griditem>
        </indx-grid>
    </body>
</html>
```

**indx-grid.html**

```html
<polymer-element name="indx-grid">
<template>
    <style>
        @host {
            :scope {
                display: block;
                margin: 20px;
                border: 2px solid #E60000;
                background: #CCC;
                height: 500px;
            }
        }
    </style>
</template>
<script>
    Polymer('indx-grid');
</script>
</polymer-element>
```

**indx-griditem.html**

```html
<polymer-element name="indx-griditem">
    <template>
        <style>
            @host {
                :scope {
                    display: block;
                    margin: 10px;
                    border: 1px solid #000;
                    border-radius: 3px;
                    background: #FFF;
                    width: 100px;
                    height: 100px;
                }
            }
        </style>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer('indx-griditem');
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Strangely enough, although I can see it in developer tools in Chrome and CSS properties are all correct, the element will not display and not even have a 'size tooltip' while inspecting it with Chrome dev tools.

Does someone have any clue about the problem here?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need `<content>` [1](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom/#toc-separation-separate) to bring in `<indx-griditem>` ("light DOM") into the `<indx-grid>`'s shadow DOM.

Demo: http://jsbin.com/eRimiJo/2/edit

**Bonus tip**: you can also use `noscript` on Polymer elements that don't setup a prototype (e.g. only call `Polymer('element-name');`

Comment: Great still applies to Polymer 1.0